# Write data to multiple files using multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, file-handling

I want to create multiple file using multiple threads, and append data (after some operation is performed) to corresponding files from their respective threads.

I tried it, but data is getting messed between threads and correct data is not added to respective files.

```
import threading
import time

exitFlag = 0

class myThread (threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.threadID = threadID
      self.name = name
      self.counter = counter
   def run(self):
      with open('file_'+count+'_logs.txt', 'a+') as result:
            result.write("Starting " + self.name)
            result.write("Exiting " + self.name)
      print ("Starting " + self.name)
      print_time(self.name, self.counter, 5)
      print ("Exiting " + self.name)

def print_time(threadName, delay, counter):
   while counter:
      if exitFlag:
         threadName.exit()
      time.sleep(delay)
      print ("%s: %s" % (threadName, time.ctime(time.time())))
      counter -= 1

myList = ['string0', 'string1', 'string2', 'string3']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    count = 0
    for data in myList:
        count += 1
        mythread = myThread(count, "Thread-" + str(count), count)
        mythread.start()
        mythread.join()
```

I expect that 4 files shall be created from 4 threads, and data from thread 1 should be written to file_1_logs.txt and so on...
But while writing data, sometimes all data is written in a single file.
How do I write this data to file correctly?

Comment: Your variable `count` does not exist inside the thread. Could it be that you mean `self.counter`?

Comment: ```count``` exists in the main, and is argument of the constructor

Comment: I know, but it does not exist **in** the thread. The thread does run separately from the main. Don't use global (or higher-scope) variables when you are working with threads.

Comment: What do you mean **in** the thread?

Comment: It is a constraint, that I have to use higher scope variables... I get data from other function that controls my thread :(

Comment: Is this your actual code? As written, it's not even going to run the threads concurrently since you `join` each one before starting the next.

Comment: No.. this is just a pseudo code.
In actual code, first all threads are started and then joined one by one.

Comment: Please post code that actually exhibits the problem. At a glance, you need to use `self.counter` in your `run` method instead of `count`.

Comment: If you post abridged examples (which is good), make sure that they behave exactly like your real code and expose the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use higher-scope or global variables in threads. Every variable (that you want to modify) must be local to the thread.

That means you need to pass the initial values of everything to the Thread constructor. The same is true for functions like your `print_time`. Either everything the function needs to do its job is passed via the arguments – or you turn it into a class method.

Consider the following changes. Note how `MyThread` is completely self-contained:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, delay, data):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.data = data
        self.delay = delay
        self.logfile = None

    def run(self):
        with open('file_%s_logs.txt' % self.threadID, 'a+') as logfile:
            self.logfile = logfile
            self.log("Starting")
            self.print_time(5)
            self.log("Exiting")
            self.logfile = None

    def print_time(self, repeat):
        for c in range(repeat):
            sleep(self.delay)
            self.log(self.data)

    def log(self, message):
        now = datetime.now().isoformat()
        formatted_line = "%s:%s:%s" % (now, self.name, message)
        print(formatted_line)
        if self.logfile:
            self.logfile.write(formatted_line + '\n')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    myList = ['string0', 'string1', 'string2', 'string3']
    threads = []

    # spawn threads
    for idx, data in enumerate(myList):
        thread = MyThread(idx, "Thread-%s" % idx, idx, data)
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

    # wait for threads to finish
    while True:
        if any(thread.is_alive() for thread in threads):
            sleep(0.1)
        else:
            print("All done.")
            break
```